# Get error severity in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, exception

How can I find the severity of errors when dealing with exceptions?
I've added an email notification whenever there is an error but for some reason I'm also getting notifications on failing validations.

```
public function report(\Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Exception) {
        $top = $e->getMessage().' on line '.$e->getLine();
        $body = $e->getTraceAsString();

        Mail::queue('emails.general', compact('top','body'), function($message) {
            $message->from('abc@abc.com','abc');
            $message->to('abc@gmail.com','abc')
                ->subject('An error on Abc');
        });

    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using and can you post your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` code please?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Just a small note, your `if` statement will always hit.  `$e` will never be anything other than `\Exception`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `report` function of `App\Exceptions\Handler` class you can do as:

```
if ($this->shouldReport($e)) {
    // send email
}
```

This will not report the exception listed in the `$dontReport` variable.

So your final code will look as:

```
public function report(\Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->shouldReport($e)) {
        $top = $e->getMessage().' on line '.$e->getLine();
        $body = $e->getTraceAsString();

        Mail::queue('emails.general', compact('top','body'), function($message) {
            $message->from('abc@abc.com','abc');
            $message->to('abc@gmail.com','abc')
                ->subject('An error on Abc');
        });
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

And also if you want to send the full stack trace of exception then you can use this [github](https://github.com/squareboat/sneaker) repo.

Comment: Good job! Can you further elaborate on the connection between the two handler classes?

Comment: You can further read about this on the docs.. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` you can inform Laravel which exceptions you want to *not* be reported.

There should be a property named `$dontReport` that you can add `ValidationException` to in order to stop it being reported and therefore stop emails being sent.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        parent::report($e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

This is my `Handler.php` file. You can see that `ValidationException::class` is in the `$dontReport` property and doesn't get reported.

Alternatively, you could modify your code to specifically just ignore `ValidationException`:

```
if ($e instanceof \Exception && !($e instanceof ValidationException)) {
    // Your email code...
```

Comment: I as well have the $dontReport variable there and ValidationException::class is also there. ValidationException doesn't get saved in the log but I am getting an email about it nevertheless. Is there any way to use $dontReport inside my mailing function to ignore all of the exceptions that appear in $dontReport ?

Comment: That's odd that they're still being reported then. Yeah there should be a way to do that. I'll update my answer. Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. It appears you've already got an answer for your question.